Best way to import React in Wordpress when working with Typescript?
Can I refer to the React / React-Dom scripts, which Wordpress enqueued, in my bundled javascript but use the -dev installed React for development?
The  javascript files are meant for a Wordpress plugin. They are React components developed in Typescript. This is not one app but multiple, separate Javascript files enqueued based on the page / route the client is viewing.
The Webpack and Typescript configs are correctly set up, so my current setup works. I'm inquiring more about optimising my current flow.
Currently I use the following bit on the first line of my .tsx files when needing any React functionality:
declare const wp: any;
const { useEffect, useState } = wp.element;

But I find this sub-optimal. That way I can't use any of the Typescript React types and installing other npm packages also creates headaches. I was doing it this way so far to keep the javascript files small and only depend on the React and React-Dom script provided by Wordpress.
Preferably I would like to do it the old fashioned way during development:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

So I guess I want to keep the files small and use what is already loaded by Wordpress but have the comfort of using proper React during development.

What about importing straight from the @wordpress/element node module package? import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element'. If you're using the @wordpress/scripts Webpack wrapper to build your scripts, it will detect the packages you're using on the page and adds them to a dependencies file, which you can use in wp_enqueue_script.

Yes, I somehow was always ignoring the official wordpress packages. But after spending some time I got it to work with the two packages @wordpress/scripts and @wordpress/element. Thank you for reminding me to use them.

Actually Wordpress provides a very comfortable way of setting this up for yourself. Like @Emiel pointed out one just needs to do the following:

install @wordpress/element and @wordpress/scripts
adjust inside package.json scripts/build to contain "wp-scripts build" and scripts/start "wp-scripts start"
Add React elements like import { useEffect, useState } from "@wordpress/element"; to your javascript / typescript.
run npm run build
require the automatically created *.asset.php folder wherever one enqueues their scripts. and add it as a dependency to the enqueue_script function.

